# Random Forest 2D line based weak learner

Tags: python, random-forest

for Random Forest 2D line based weak learner, we have ax+by+c=0
I understand that x and y are features and a,b,c are used as splitting points. But how will we select those split points? from randomly selected number within feature range or just any random numbers? and if from feature range than which feature range?

Thanks

Comment: Questions seems misunderstod . Could you provide a refrence for this *Random Forest 2D*